# Having issue with xhr.send(blob) for Django, sending audio file

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, blob

I am trying to send the blob to the backend but it failed.
[image: the error shown in console]

Code for views.py

```
@login_required   
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@require_http_methods({"GET","POST"})
def record_audio(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, 'recording/record.html')
blob= request.FILES.get("blob", None)
if blob is None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Missing audio-blob parameter")

now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
filename = f"{request.user.username}_{now}.wav"
filepath = Path.joinpath(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "recordings",filename)
 
with open(filepath, 'wb') as audio_file:
    for chunk in blob.chunks():
        audio_file.write(chunk)

return HttpResponse(status=HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT)
```

Code for the sending blob part:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/record-audio/', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("MyCustomHeader", "Put anything you need in here, like an ID");
            // console.log(blob)
            // downloadBlob(blob)
            xhr.send(blob);
```

I use jquery-1.12.3.js